# c++ matrix multiplication with two 1d arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

For an assignment I had to write a `MatrixProduct.cpp` which has to be able to multiply two 1-dimensional c++ arrays. I wrote a method `multipoly` which should multiply two 1d arrays but it doesn't. I am new to C++ so don't be too hard on me.

```
double* multiply(double m1i[], double m2i[], int s1, int s2, int s3) {
    double* matrixa = new double[s1*s2];
    double* matrixb = new double[s2*s3];
    double* matrixc = new double[s1*s3];
    double sum;
    for (int i = 0; i < (s1 * s2); i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < s3; j++)
        {
            float sum = 0;
            for (int k = 0; k < s2; k++)
            {
                sum = sum + matrixa[i] * matrixb[((k - 1) * s3) + (j - 1)];
                matrixc[i * s3 + k] = sum;
            }

        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    return matrixc;
}
```

thanks for your help:D

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking with your question, what specific error are you getting?

Comment: you're passing in `m1i` and `m2i`, but you read from uninitialized memory in `matrixa` and `matrixb`?

Comment: @PeterT is right, plus your function has a nasty memory leak. `matrixa` and `matrixb` are never deleted. `matrixc` is only deleted if the caller doesn't forget to do it.

Comment: Take care of matrixb[((k - 1) * s3) + (j - 1)]; you have out of bounds access (negative offset). Also do not forget to delete your allocated memory at the end: for instance delete[] matrixa; (or even better use a std::unique_ptr). Also and it is easy, edit your post and use better name for s1,s2,s3 variables. Maybe something like A_row_size or B_col_size... Otherwise we do not understand your code (and cannot help)